# How can I extract data from a webpage when the data has no selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, xpath

I am writing some JavaScript to extract data from a third-party website. The data that I need to extract is formatted as such:

```
<!-- a bunch of extra stuff before this -->
<tr>
    <td>Keyword: </td>
    <td>
        Value
        <a>...</a>
        Other stuff I don't care about
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- a bunch of extra stuff after this -->
```

What I'd like to do is search the DOM for "Keyword:" and then grab "Value" from the next TD.

Comment: maybe you need to use `xpath`?

Comment: check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5mzxyogn/)

Comment: xpath might be something like: `(//tr[td[.='Keyword:']]/td)[2]/text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector would do this.

For your specific example:

```
$( "td:contains('Keyword: ')" ).next().contents()[0].val();
```

First it finds  that contains "Keyword: ". Then it finds the next element, then it splits that into an array of parts, then it selects the first element in that array, then gets the value of that element.

Comment: This returned a jQuery object which was hard to work with. Building off of this, I was able to tag on a regex to extract just "Value": `$("td:contains('Keyword:')").next().html().match(/^\s*(\w+)/)[1]`

Comment: I made a mistake there. If you put a `.val()` at the end it would have gotten the correct value. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this. You will have to use the `contains` selector and the `siblings` api to achieve the same.

You can read more about `contains` [here](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

You can read more about `siblings` [here](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Example for when there is only one sibling:

`alert($("td:contains('Key')").siblings().html());`

Example for when there are multiple siblings:

`$("td:contains('Key')").siblings().each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});`